# Why do I have to copy mingw DLLs manually when using windeployqt?

Tags: windows, qt, windeployqt

Just downloaded Qt Creator and compiled my application.
I am using windeployqt on the command line since I did not find any option in Qt creator itself.
When I use it on my binary I still have to copy DLLs like libgcc_s_seh-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll and libwinpthread-1.dll from my Qt installation directory `C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\bin` into my deployment directory or otherwise I cannot start the .exe file.
The same happens if I am trying to start it in my target build directory without the Qt Creator.

Shouldn't windeployqt or the Qt Creator copy those DLLs into the build and deployment directory, so you can run the .exe properly?!